Euler's Elements of Algebra Solution Method, Section III Ch. XI Problem 3.
I've been going through and writing up solutions for Euler's Elements of Algebra Practice Questions in my free time, and I can't seem to find the path to Euler's Provided Solution. Here's Euler's question:
One Sessa, an Indian, having first invented the game
of chess, shewed it to his prince, who was so delighted
with it, that he promised him any reward he should ask;
upon which Sessa requested that he might be allowed one
grain of wheat for the first square on the chess board, two
for the second, and so on, doubling continually, to 64,
the whole number of squares. Now, supposing a pint to
contain 7680 of those grains, and one quarter to be worth
ll. 7s. 6d., it is required to compute the value of the
whole sum of grains. Ans. 644814882961.
I know from problem 2, the conversion for money is 20 s. to 1 l., and 12 d. per 1 s.
( pence/pennies := d. , shillings := s.,  and pounds := l.)
I have been utilizing the assumption that there are 2 pints per quarter, though I'm wondering if due to the age of the text that I am under a wrong volume assumption. This has been frustrating me the past couple of days, and I don't want to proceed to the next section without solving this mystery first.
Any insight into where I could be going wrong here would be very helpful! Certainly, Euler has the correct solution here, and it would be greatly historically interesting if this was a case of myself succumbing to modern volume assumptions.
Thanks!

To clarify, I understand the chessboard sum is $2^{64} - 1$ and am having troubles using this to convert to the correct monetary solution.

A quart is two pints, but a quarter isn't a quart. I'm not sure what a quarter actually is. I have found a source which says a quarter is eight bushels, but I forgot long ago how many pints there are in a bushel. Also, I think there's a typo in the figure given for the worth of a quarter. The other source gives it as $27$ shillings $6$ pence. It gives the answer as $6450468216285$ pounds $17$ shillings $3$ pence and $3{32757\over32768}$q. I don't know what q stands for.

Another source agrees with one pound seven and six, and gives the same answer you give, except that where your answer has a final digit $1$, this source omits the $1$, and puts a pound sign in front of the number.

27 shillings 6 pence would be the equivalent of 1l. 7s. 6d. Thank you for the insight! I just got to work so will see if your different answer from another source follows the mathematics. 13 digits as a pound solution 'out the gate' seems a much more reasonable answer. I will play around with the bushels and pints conversion and see if I can arrive at Euler's solution. Seems like an imperial bushel is 64 pints, but I will have to see. Many thanks!

Also, I believe the copy-paste formatting skews the representation of pounds. Euler utilizes the lower case L "l." notation for pounds, instead of the calligraphic capital latin L with a bar.

P.P.S. q is 'quarters' or as originally transcribed in the text, "farthings". farthings are 1/4th the value of a penny/pence. These conversions are upheld in Problem 2 from the same chapter questions.

Thanks for clearing up the meaning of "q". By the way, I'm very skeptical about this really being an exercise due to Euler. Euler was Swiss, and worked in Russia and elsewhere on the Continent. Why would he write an exercise using British money?

That is a good question. Certainly British currency wasn't the most widely used in 1760s Europe, as Euler was in Berlin at the time. And the original text was published in Russian.

Aha. You are correct in being skeptical. Insofar as I understand, the original Russian publication does not have any practice problems. I haven't been able to find the French translation thereafter, but it seems that the 1824 English translation from the French edition was the first to introduce the practice problems! Hence why the currency in the practice questions all revolves around using the British currency.

Russian text: https://archive.org/details/1_euler_universal/page/n1/mode/2up?view=theater       \                                                                                                                                     1824 English Text: https://archive.org/details/elementsofalgebr00euleuoft

Upon further investigation, the problems in fact vary from each English translation. This problem appears in the John Hewlett translation, but not the Charles Tayler.

The Russian text is also a translation "пер. П.Иноходцева и И.Юдина" (by P. Inokhodtsev and I. Yudin). At the Euler Archive it is listed as originally published in German.

@ccprog Nice catch! Further, indeed the practice questions do not arise until the English translations, as the German text you linked and the 1807 French do not include them either! Thank you for the information :]

@GerryMyerson What is the other source you mention in the comment above? I'd like to use that source over the one I currently use. "The other source gives it as 27
shillings 6
pence. It gives the answer as 6450468216285
pounds 17
shillings 3
pence and 33275732768
q."

I don't remember. I typed a few words from the problem into Google, and it came back with a dozen books (counting some which were just later editions of others), and I didn't keep track of which ones I actually looked at or which one I quoted. If you paste 6450468216285 into Google, you, too, will get links to several sources.

Originally, I searched Google for the phrase,
supposing a pint to contain 7680 of those grains

Thank you! I appreciate your help!

@Gerry Myerson;
Per @JustCal on the history stack exchange, we have
"This is solved by reading through the Wikipedia definition of a quarter:
These copies describe the "London quarter" as notionally derived from eight "London bushels" of eight wine gallons of eight pounds of 15 ounces of 20 pennyweights of 32 grains of wheat, taken whole from the middle of an ear;
So a quarter equals eight bushels of (x) eight gallons of (x) eight pounds...
Eight pounds=1 gallon. This is the same formulation we use today, 8 pints = 1 gallon. This is confirmed in another wiki entry here, where the pound is expressed in grains of wheat:
...At that time, the pound unit in use in England was the Tower pound, equal to 7,680 Tower grains (also known as wheat grains).
There is a familiar number which ties back to the ops' question. So a pint is the equivalent of a pound = 1/8 of a gallon. Therefore the Quarter = 8x8x8=512 pints/pounds of grain."
So, taking our sum of $2^{64} - 1$ and dividing by $7680*512=3932160$ to get a unit amount and convert via $330 d.$ per unit, we arrive at your suggested correct solution of
6450468216285 pounds
17 shillings
3 pence
and $ 3 * \dfrac{332757}{32768}$ farthings!

As the question appears in English translations, with the practice questions of the text themselves being an addition by the English translations, Euler's Elements of Algebra maintains the solution as 64481488296 l., which notably mathematically does not utilize a 1 quarter to 512 pints conversion.
However, in an 1831 Mathematics text A Course of Mathematics: For the Use of Academies as Well as Private Tuition: in Two Volumes, Volume 1 by Charles Hutton, added onto by Olinthus Gregory and Robert Adrian, on page 144 question 27 we see the solution that matches utilizing the conversion of 1 quarter to 512 pints, given as:

Ans. $6450468216285 l. 17 s. 3 d. 3  \dfrac{32757}{32768} q.$

